# bind kendo dropdown from ajax post result

Tags: jquery, json, kendo-ui

I have been searching it for many hours but did not get any solution yet.

here is the kendo dropdown

```
 <div id="formMain" class="at-form>
  <span data-name="ERP_DimensionCodesList" id="ERP_DimensionCodesList" data-type="picklist"></span>
</div>
```

here is ajax call

```
  window.Page.Data.getDimensionCodeList = function (dimension, company) {
            window.Page.get(
                "/api/ERPIntegrationDimensionSetup/GetDimensionCodeList"
                , { dimension: dimension, company: company }
                , window.Page.Data.dataReceivedDimension
            );
        }
        window.Page.Data.dataReceivedDimension = function (data) {
            debugger;
 var dataSource = [];
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                dataSource.push({ text: data[i].ListID, value: data[i].ListName })
            };
            $("#ERP_DimensionCodesList").kendoDropDownList({
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
                dataSource: dataSource
            });
}
```

[image]

As shown in picture above, data is not empty but it is not binding data in drop down. How to achieve it? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it show something in dropdown? I mean, does it write "No data found" or [object][object]?

Comment: no it is not binding anything

Answer (score 2):

I think, the problem is your dataTextField & dataValueField declarations.
Setting dataSource is not enough. You should declare your dataTextField and dataValueField according to your object properties.
In your case it should be like this:

```
..
dataTextField:"ListName",
dataValueField: "ListID",
..
```

Comment: I disagree, he is creating datasource with text and value properties (in loop) and so dataTextField nd dataValueField are correct.

Comment: where on earth do you see that?  he's clearly naming them listname and listid.  That control doesn't have the slightest id what to show unless you tell it.